# "Non splendeat toga, ne sordeat quidem"

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, translation-explanation, seneca

In Seneca's Epistulae morales ad Lucilium (Letter 5):

> Non splendeat toga, ne sordeat quidem.

What exactly does *ne...quidem* mean here? It is certainly not "*not even*? In Leob we read the translation: "Do not wear too fine, nor yet too frowzy, a toga." But still not sure what the sentiment: is it "The toga does not have to be fancy *but just* not a dirty one." or "the toga should not be fancy *nor* dirty." In this particular case it might be quite small a distinction, but I can think of other cases where the distinction is notable. Is there any implied *et* or *sed* in the Latin? What is the function of *quidem*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would fit under definition 6.b for *nē* in *OLD*:

> not...either, neither.

Therefore, 'Your toga should not be bright (but) not dingy either.'

In fact, the *OLD* entry cites this passage. Others that are cited include:

Cicero, *De inventione* 1.47:

> *nam si Rhodiis turpe non est portorium locare, ne Hermocreonti quidem turpe est conducere.*
>
> For if it is not dishonourable for the Rhodians to lease out their harbour dues, it is not dishonourable for Hermocreon to take the contract either.

Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum* 14.12.2:

> *quem quidem sui Caesarem salutabant, Philippus non, itaque ne nos quidem*
>
> His own people addressed him [Octavius] as 'Caesar'; but Philippus did not, and therefore I did not either.

Livy 21.18.11:

> si uos non tenent foedera uestra nisi ex auctoritate aut iussu uestro icta, ne nos quidem Hasdrubalis foedus quod nobis insciis icit obligare potuit.
>
> If you are not bound by your treaties, unless they are struck at your own instance or command, the treaty of Hasdrubal, which he struck without our knowledge, is not binding on us either.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most likely reading is simply "your toga should be neither fancy nor dirty".
I would not try to give individual meanings to *ne* and *quidem*, as *ne quidem* is a pretty common set phrase meaning something along the lines of "and not".

The Loeb translation strikes me as a good one, and the point made makes sense.